# How to handle common steps in Behave

Tags: python-behave

I have 4 feature files like login, add to cart, search by product, shipping method calculation. All 4 are separate feature file and all have first 4 steps are exact same like below :

```
Given I go to website
When I click on the login button
Then I enter username and password
And I verify I am logged in successfully
```

In behave if I use the same steps in all feature files, it does not work. It has an Ambiguous Step error.

My goal is to log in first in all 4 feature files and then move to the next corresponding step.

**The error I am facing :**

```
raise AmbiguousStep(message % (new_step, existing_step))
behave.step_registry.AmbiguousStep: @given('I am loggedin into website') has already been defined in
  existing step @given('I am loggedin into website') at features/steps/Steps_cart.py:5
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact error you are facing?

Comment: @VikasMulaje - I have added error in question if that helps.

Comment: The error usually happens when you have 2 steps with the same name defined in a step file. It's the same if you have the same step in 2 different step files. Check if you don't have `@given('I am loggedin into website')` step defined twice.

Comment: @Krzysztof - You are right But that I know. My question is how can I handle this? If I have login scenarios in all feature files then of course I will have same steps in every file.

Comment: @HelpingHands - Steps are shared across all feature files usually. I am not sure what is your case, but if you need the same step to be run in those all 4 feature files, you should remove this duplicated step. Why do you need the same 2 steps? You have 4 different applications that require to login?

Comment: I have 2 scenarios. When I run all feature files together , I set like run login feature file first and then run all other. BUT now if I want to run single feature file then I will have to login first and that is why I have put login steps in all feature files.